# “Maven Project” option is not showing in Jenkins under New Item section (latest version 2.60.1 for Windows)

Tags: maven, jenkins, plugins

Open **Jenkins server**, go to >> **New Item**
As i want to work with Maven Project but i cant find **'maven project'** option available there.

►To add Maven Project in ***New Item*** Page,

just go to **Manage Jenkins** >> **Manage Plugin**,

click on **Available**  Tab,

In the filter box enter *"Maven plugin"* and  you will get search result as *"Unleash Maven Plugin"*,

√ enable the check-box, click on **"Download now and install after restart"**

Below screenshot will help you more-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

1) Go to Jenkins Dashboard ->Manage Jenkins ->Manage plugins ->Available ->Maven Integration ->Install

2) Go to Manage Jenkins->Global tool configuration->Maven -> Add Maven_home variable value (i.e. path of the maven file on your system)

3) Go to Jenkins Dashboard -> New Item -> Maven Project option will be available

Answer (score 0):

Here is a latest updates as per Jenkins the Plugin name to installed is changed to "Maven Integration" highlighted below:

PFB

[image]